Is #sat impossible for quantum computing algorithms?
The whole space must be searched for #P, which appears to require determinism.
Of course, checking the answer is rather difficult.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What does #P-complete mean in practice?
The program numsat works on general cnf,
using complete search with components.
I cannot fathom anything but deterministic search.
Any nondeterministic answer would be a poor guess.
Here is some state of the art data,
possible food for theoretical thought...
Can anyone validate growth of these series?
Is #sat of monotone 2cnf #P complete? Yes.
Here is what that means in practice.
100 variables is near the practical limit.
The number of models grows roughly as 2^(2n/3)
The number of assumptions is roughly 2^(n/3)
Components correlate with assumptions.
Inferences are roughly ten times assumptions.
The program is available by email: smith23801530 at gmail dot com
Joseph Daniel Pehoushek
Here are experimental results on random monotone 2cnf.
#a assumptions #c components #i inferences (billions remainder)
Monotone 2cnf two occurrences per variable.
m2d2n10.cnf,   (#P 104 : #a 10 #c 12 (#i 0 87))
m2d2n20.cnf,   (#P 10340 : #a 36 #c 39 (#i 0 349))
m2d2n30.cnf,   (#P 784740 : #a 124 #c 142 (#i 0 1405))
m2d2n40.cnf,   (#P 313679080 : #a 1694 #c 1969 (#i 0 20773))
m2d2n50.cnf,   (#P 16886248407 : #a 2230 #c 2591 (#i 0 27356))
m2d2n60.cnf,   (#P 1548010934229 : #a 3200 #c 3719 (#i 0 39321))
m2d2n70.cnf,   (#P 583600104724728 : #a 452192 #c 525609 (#i 0 5589411))
m2d2n80.cnf,   (#P 44361287415139863 : #a 196216 #c 228073 (#i 0 2425169))
m2d2n90.cnf,   (#P 3340741443818080654 : #a 2443636 #c 2840380 (#i 0 30206260))
c[bigsums (tfiles 9 tforms 9) (numberp 3385687896549602145 zeromos 0)(retros 3099338 bigoh 0 billion 38310131)]
m2d2n91.cnf,   (#P 8838590596190174105 : #a 30693896 #c 35677325 (#i 0 379417564))
m2d2n92.cnf,   (#P 19036965853881143224 : #a 1573169064 #c 1828587185 (#i 19 446489945))
m2d2n93.cnf,   (#P 16371066159636605172 : #a 35428 #c 41178 (#i 0 437553))
m2d2n94.cnf,   (#P 24631033372012180330 : #a 84160 #c 97824 (#i 0 1039971))
m2d2n95.cnf,   (#P 23112230478857377935 : #a 13692 #c 15914 (#i 0 168873))
m2d2n96.cnf,   (#P 146335589705051903772 : #a 54448822270 #c 63289077438 (#i 673 60841893))
m2d2n97.cnf,   (#P 181526497832196124785 : #a 17278 #c 20082 (#i 0 213179))
m2d2n98.cnf,   (#P 414737590951956195798 : #a 17490830 #c 20330623 (#i 0 216209838))
m2d2n99.cnf,   (#P 671053183690751719166 : #a 896455194 #c 1042002744 (#i 11 81394252))
c[bigsums (tfiles 9 tforms 9) (numberp 1505642748640533424287 zeromos 0)(retros 56966781812 bigoh 704 billion 186213068)]
three occurrences per variable
m2d3n10.cnf,   (#P 82 : #a 14 #c 18 (#i 0 170))
m2d3n20.cnf,   (#P 6140 : #a 260 #c 294 (#i 0 3364))
m2d3n30.cnf,   (#P 177408 : #a 878 #c 1022 (#i 0 11198))
m2d3n40.cnf,   (#P 21848783 : #a 8384 #c 9968 (#i 0 109402))
m2d3n50.cnf,   (#P 2999666797 : #a 49810 #c 60229 (#i 0 663636))
m2d3n60.cnf,   (#P 186678215369 : #a 641262 #c 779593 (#i 0 8475401))
m2d3n70.cnf,   (#P 8942241918897 : #a 1080232 #c 1290637 (#i 0 13940124))
m2d3n80.cnf,   (#P 490045501565302 : #a 15036360 #c 17952035 (#i 0 194044109))
m2d3n90.cnf,   (#P 65577822144996044 : #a 130423610 #c 157913680 (#i 1 694727523))
c[bigsums (tfiles 9 tforms 9) (numberp 66076999588394822 zeromos 0)(retros 147240810 bigoh 1 billion 911974927)]
m2d3n100.cnf,   (#P 12107519305305449401 : #a 1173792016 #c 1421447938 (#i 15 224973309))
m2d3n110.cnf,   (#P 583435111918994703426 : #a 4945924512 #c 1677068293 (#i 64 280963526))
m2d3n120.cnf,   (#P 35950128588370803291696 : #a 54134596580 #c 298041404 (#i 698 238705472))
m2d3n130.cnf,   (#P 1470948632659714863050325 : #a 75475643130 #c 1341975296 (#i 976 724138128))
